# SQL count unique occurrences of gender

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 Tables (Demographic),(LINK) and (Admission)

```
SELECT SUM(CASE dmg.dmg_Sex WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS male,
       SUM(CASE dmg.dmg_Sex WHEN 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS female,
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2011' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/03/2011'
```

Im trying to sum the genders in date range.
This is not working though, Am I on the right track?

Just doing the plain query without the `SUM` and `CASE` works 100%.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `This is not working though` ?

Comment: You have a comma after `female`, which will cause a syntax error.  You should also use ISO standard formats for dates.

Comment: can u try `case when dmg.dmg_Sex = 'Male'` instead

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ---> Face Palm ....   Thanks, that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY

```
SELECT dmg.dmg_Sex, COUNT (dmg.dmg_Sex)
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2011' 
AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/03/2011'
GROUP BY dmg.dmg_Sex
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. This works as-well. (I had a comma after 'Female' ), but yours is categorized so wins.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE dmg.dmg_Sex WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS male,
       SUM(CASE dmg.dmg_Sex WHEN 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS female
FROM Demographic dmg
JOIN LINK lnk ON lnk.lnk_dmgID = dmg.dmg_ID
JOIN Admission adm ON adm.adm_ID = lnk.lnk_admID
WHERE adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2011' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/03/2011'
```